# how can I calculate $\mathbb{E}(X|X+Y=a)$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed non-negative random variables.

How can I calculate $\mathbb{E}(X|X+Y=a)$?

Comment: it is a good idea to add what have you tried so far in the question.

Comment: Read [these instructions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for asking for help on homework questions.

Comment: Add the `self-study` tag if this is course work, and, direct your questions toward asking for hints or interpretive help rather than answers to the course work itself, please.

Answer (score 3):

One quick answer arises by noticing the symmetric role of $X$ and $Y$:

$\mathbb{E}(Y|X+Y=a)=\mathbb{E}(X|X+Y=a)=u$

Therefore:

$a=\mathbb{E}(X+Y|X+Y=a)=\mathbb{E}(Y|X+Y=a)+\mathbb{E}(X|X+Y=a)=2u$

from which $u=a/2$